# Retrieving nested values from PostgreSQL JSON columns

Tags: json, postgresql

Our database contains a table "log" like this:

```
id | purchases (json)
1    {"apple":{"price":5,"seller":"frank"}, "bred":{"price":3,"seller":"kathy"}}
2    {"milk":{"price":3,"seller":"anne"}, "banana":{"price":2,"seller":"frank"}}
3    {"bred":{"price":4,"seller":"kathy"}}
```

We would like to retrieve all records containing `"seller":"kathy"`. We tried simple queries like this:

```
SELECT id FROM log WHERE purchases ->> 'seller' LIKE 'kathy'
SELECT id FROM log WHERE purchases = '{"seller":"kathy"}'
```

We researched here and elsewhere for some hours ... it seems a bit more complex because the values are nested? We found e.g. some java or pgplsql implementations, but we are still hoping there is a "pure SQL" way. What would be a proper solution? Or should we re-organize our content like this:

```
id | purchases (json)
1    [{"product":"apple","price":5,"seller":"frank"},{"product":"bred","price":3,"seller":"kathy"}]
2    [{"product":"milk","price":3,"seller":"anne"},{"product":"banana","price":2,"seller":"frank"}]
3    [{"product":"bred","price":4,"seller":"kathy"}]
```

But what we found, this would be even more complex, because we have to explode the arrays within the query. Any short hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `json_each()` and `#>>` [**Postgres JSON functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html):

```
WITH log(id,purchases) AS ( VALUES
  (1,'{"apple":{"price":5,"seller":"frank"}, "bred":{"price":3,"seller":"kathy"}}'::JSON),
  (2,'{"milk":{"price":3,"seller":"anne"}, "banana":{"price":2,"seller":"frank"}}'::JSON),
  (3,'{"bred":{"price":4,"seller":"kathy"}}'::JSON)
)
SELECT log.* FROM log,
  json_each(log.purchases) as purchase
WHERE
  purchase.value#>>'{seller}' = 'kathy';
```

Result:

```
 id |                                  purchases                                  
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"apple":{"price":5,"seller":"frank"}, "bred":{"price":3,"seller":"kathy"}}
  3 | {"bred":{"price":4,"seller":"kathy"}}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: perfect, helps a lot, thanks @dmitry, I understand much more now.